# PHP User Authentication

Tags: php, authentication

I've been teaching myself PHP out of a couple of books, from the W3Schools site and using a whole bunch of posts of Stack Overflow.

To try and put something into practice I'm trying to make a small image gallery that implements a user authentication system. Users have a security access that determines wether they have read, read write access or can administrate other users etc. I've only gotten as far as the login and add user stuff.

I've modelled it off my work, where everyone has a unique employee ID and 8 digit email ID.

I know this is a long shot, but I'm just wondering if anyone would be able to take a look and tell me if my code is heading down the right track? It's so different putting something 'real world' like this together from the basic examples provided in books. Any comments and suggestions would be appreciated....

**login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php       
   // Connect to the database
   include('./helpers/db.php');
   include('./helpers/general.php');

   // Check if the user has submitted their details.
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       $loginId = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['userId']));
       $loginPass = htmlspecialchars(sha1($_POST['password']));

       // Check if they've submitted blank details.
       if (!checkLoginId($loginId) || (!checkPassword($_POST['password']))) {
           $errorMsg = "Please enter a valid username or password!";
       }

       else {
       // Select the details we want for the session info.
       $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT firstName, lastName, securityLevel FROM 
                            userDetails WHERE registeredNumber = :loginId 
                            AND password = :loginPass" );
       $stmt->bindParam(':loginId', $loginId);
       $stmt->bindParam(':loginPass', $loginPass);
       $stmt->execute();

            // Make sure the user is found, and that there security level is 1 or more.
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $userDetails = $stmt->fetch();

                if ($userDetails['securityLevel'] < 1) {
                    $errorMsg = "Insufficient access for this user.";
                }

                else {

                // Start a new session and set up the regularly used info.
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['userID'] = $loginId;
                $_SESSION['fname'] = $userDetails['firstName'];
                $_SESSION['lname'] = $userDetails['lastName'];
                $_SESSION['security'] = $userDetails['securityLevel'];
                header("Location: ./browser/");
                }
            }

            else {
                $errorMsg = "Invalid User ID or Password!";
            }
       }
   }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
       body {font-family:sans-serif;}
       .warning {color:red;font-weight:bold;}
       #login {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:200px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;padding:20px;}
</style>
<body>
   <!-- Display the login form -->
    <div id="login">
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <?php 
        if (isset($errorMsg)) {
            echo '<span class="warning">'. $errorMsg . '</span>';
        } 
        ?>
        <p><label for="userId">User Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="userId"
              title="Enter your User ID:">
        </p>
        <p><label for="pasword">Password:</label><br/>
            <input type="password" maxlength="12" name="password"
              title="Enter your password:"/>
        </p>
        <p><input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dam';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '****';

// Try and connect to the database and catch the error if it doesn't work.

try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    echo "Connected to Database<br/>";
}

catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    print "Error! " . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>';
    die();
}

?>
```

**general.php**

```
<?php

// Checks wether the loginID/Registered Number is valid
function checkLoginId($login) {
if ($login == '' || $login == NULL || (!is_numeric($login))) {
    return 0;
}

else return 1;
}

// Checks whether the password is valid
function checkPassword($password) {
if ($password == '' || $password == NULL) {
    return 0;
}

else return 1;
}

function verifyNewUser($userID, $upass, $fname, $lname, $email) {
$hasErrors = 0;
$errorMsg = array();

if ($userID == '' || $userID == NULL || (!is_numeric($userID)) || (strlen($userID) != 5)) {
    $hasErrors++;
    $errorMsg[] = "User ID is either missing, or does not have 5 digits";
}

if ($upass == '' || $upass == NULL || (strlen($upass) <  6)) {
    $hasErrors++;
    $errorMsg[] = "Password is either missing, or does not meet minimum length of six";
}

if ($fname == '' || $fname == NULL || empty($fname)) {
    $hasErrors++;
    $errorMsg[] = "First name is missing.";
}

if ($lname == '' || $lname == NULL || empty($lname)) {
    $hasErrors++;
    $errorMsg[] = "Last name is missing.";
}

if ($email == '' || $email == NULL || empty($email) || (strlen($email) != 8)) {
    $hasErrors++;
    $errorMsg[] = "Check email id, should be 8 characters.";
}

if ($hasErrors == 0) {
    return 1;

}

else {
    echo "Returning with errors<br/>";
    return $errorMsg;
    } 
}
?>
```

**adduser.php**

```
include ("./helpers/general.php");
include('./helpers/db.php');

session_start();

// If the user isn't logged in, send them away...
if (!(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] != '')) {
header("Location: ./login.php");
exit();
}

// Get the users full name so we can politely tell them to rack off if they 
// don't have sufficient access to add users.
$uname = $_SESSION['fname'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['lname'];

// Check if the user has the security clearence to add a new user:
if ($_SESSION['security'] != 4) {
echo "Sorry $uname, only level 4 administrators can manage users.<br/>";
echo '<a href="./browser/">Back to Browser</a>';
exit();
}

// Check if they have submitted the form and validate the input
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$userID = htmlspecialchars($_POST['registeredNumber']);
$upass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
$fname = ucfirst(htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstName']));
$lname = ucfirst(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastName']));
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailID']);
$secLev = $_POST['securityLevel'];
$creator = $_SESSION['userID'];

$valid = verifyNewUser($userID, $upass, $fname, $lname, $email);

if ($valid == 1) {
    // Encrypt the password
    $upass = sha1($upass);

    // Create the array to feed the SQL statement.
    $data = array($userID, $upass, $fname, $lname, $email, $secLev, date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $creator);

    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO userDetails VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->execute($data);
    $dbh->commit();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "Success, new user $fname $lname added!<br/>";
        echo "Email ID: $email<br/>";
        echo "Security Level: $secLev<br/>";
    }
}    

else if (isset($valid)) {
    foreach($valid as $error) {
        echo '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">' . $error . "<span><br/>";
    }
}
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add A New User</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="adduser.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="registeredNumber">Registered Number:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="5" name="registeredNumber"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" maxlength="12" name="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="firstName">First Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="20" name="firstName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="lastName">Last Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="20" name="lastName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="emailID">Email ID:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="8" name="emailID"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="securityLevel">Security Level:</label></td>
            <td>
                <select name="securityLevel">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">0 - No Access</option>
                    <option value="1">1 - Read Access</option>
                    <option value="2">2 - Read/Write Access</option>
                    <option value="3">3 - Read/Write/Delete Access</option>
                    <option value="4">4 - User Administrator</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
 </html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php

// Destroy the session and go to the login screen.
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

Comment: I'd suggest against W3Schools: http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are serious security problems with your approach.

The biggest problem is you are storing the password in the database. You do not need to store the password in the database, that is a terrible idea that could be grounds for someone to sue your pants off in court.

There are a variety of encryption and hashing options to let you build a system like this without storing the password in the database, and it is standard procedure to use one of them. Anybody who doesn't is asking for problems in future (google search for "PSN password leak").

One good option is PBKDF2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2

However, that is just the most obvious problem. There are some other things you're not doing perfectly and this really is something you need to learn how to do properly, or you should not attempt it at all. Even if you're using PBKDF2 you still need to learn how to use it properly.

I recommend listening to almost every episode of Security Now before attempting to write your own authentication system. http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm

Comment: Thanks @Abhi will definitely take a look at the links you've provided. Cheers.

Comment: Hey @AbhiBeckert I've taken a look through the article you mention. I've sha1'd the password before storing it in the database. Even if I am to encrypt the password using the PBKDF2 method, don't I still have to store that password in the database? Or are you just saying to never store clear text passwords in a database? Thanks again!

Comment: Disregard my above comment I understand now.

Comment: sha1 is not strong enough by itself. It is designed for massive inputs (as in 4GB), and is very fast. Being fast makes your passwords vulnerable to brute force attacks, especially since most users have weak passwords (anything less than 100 characters long can easily be brute forced with sha1). PBKDF2 is designed to be configured so that it takes at least one tenth of a second to hash a single password on your server (you will need to play with the config to find out what settings will give this result), making brute force extremely difficult and expensive.